# QML object var property is null QVariant(QJSValue, ) from cpp

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm using Qt5.5 (5.5.1-3 from archlinux x86_64 repos) and want to read qml object property from cpp, no luck yet:

**qml part:**

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    signal doSomething()
    signal myDataChanged()
    property string myString: ""
    property var myObject: ({})
    onDoSomething(): {
        myString = "myStringValue"
        myObject = {"foo":"bar"}    
        myDataChanged()
    }
}
```

**cpp part:**

```
void MyClass::processChangedData() {
    qDebug()<<sender()->property("myString");
    qDebug()<<sender()->property("myObject");
}
```

myDataChanged() signal is connected to MyClass::processChangedData()

**output:**

```
QVariant(QString, "myString")
QVariant(QJSValue, )
```

Can you help me? I want to get the data of the qml object property from cpp part.

Comment: Since the answer is correct, given tour comment below, please accept It. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you should be able to do:

```
auto js = sender()->property("myObject").value<QJSValue>();
qDebug() << js.property("foo").toString();
```

and use other methods in QJSValue.

Comment: It's not obvious for me yet (so I've decided to simplify my data structures :),
but your example definetly works!
Thank you, Vladimir!